# How to run Python + Qt application in Squish testing tool?

Tags: python, qt, squish

I am having a trouble with starting testing my Python + Qt4.8 application using Squish.
I am new to that, so if anyone has some experience with using Squish, please read my question.

So I have a couple of Python files which make my application.
The Squish IDE requires an .exe or .bat file in order to start recording. So I successfully generated .exe from all .py files using PyInstaller. When I open the .exe file generated it works fine.

Then I select New Test Suite in Squish I select that .exe I mentioned.
It seems to be fine, but when I try to start recording, Squish cannot open my application. I get an error message like the picture below. I am sure I am using Squish with the right version of Qt. I read about the problem and I found out that it might be because I am using debug version of my application. So do anyone know how can I make my application as non-debug? Or is there any other way to fix this problem? Any help will be really appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I found the information:

> py2exe distributions: Exclude Qt libraries With py2exe on Windows the
> Qt libraries must be excluded from the distribution/.exe file.
>
> This is required because Squish for Qt only supports application that
> dynamically load the Qt libraries.

But I tried to use py2exe and excluded the libraries. Maybe I am excluding the wrong ones? Does anyone know which exactly libraries should be excluded? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

@Nela, all Qt libraries included in your packaged application must be excluded (QtCore4.dll, etc.).

If it still does not work please contact froglogic's technical support and provide the support information (Help > Collect Support Information...) directly after reproducing the problem.